# Ansible to register to a dictionary or dynamic variable for several tasks

Tags: ansible

In Ansible I have two separate tasks to get the list of existing services for redhat 6 and 7, they register to a variable, then I have another task that stops those services, if I use the same variable it gets overwritten by the last task, so it does not stop anything.

Is there  a way of distinguishing between the two results? and yet only use one task to stop the services? I tried dynamic var names or creating a dictionary, but none work.

thanks

```
  - name: Get registered services
      command: bash -c "chkconfig --list | awk '{print $1}'"
      register:  loaded_services_{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}
      when: (( ansible_os_family == "RedHat" ) and ( ansible_distribution_major_version == "6" ))
      changed_when: False
      tags: test

    - name: Get registered services
      command: bash -c "systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | cut -d. -f1"
      register: loaded_services_{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}
      when: (( ansible_os_family == "RedHat" ) and ( ansible_distribution_major_version == "7" ))
      changed_when: False
      tags: test

    - name: shutdown unnecessary services
      service: name={{ item }} enabled=no state=stopped
      with_items: "{{ disable_services | intersect(loaded_services_{{ansible_distribution_major_version}}.stdout_lines)}}"
      when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and  ansible_distribution_major_version == "6"
      tags:
        - harden
        - test
      ignore_errors: yes
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with blocks, first in this way:

```
  - block:  
    - name: Get registered services
      command: bash -c "chkconfig --list | awk '{print $1}'"
      register:  loaded_services
      changed_when: False
      tags: test
    when: (( ansible_os_family == "RedHat" ) and ( ansible_distribution_major_version == "6" ))

  - block:  
    - name: Get registered services
      command: bash -c "systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | cut -d. -f1"
      register: loaded_services
      changed_when: False
      tags: test
    when: (( ansible_os_family == "RedHat" ) and ( ansible_distribution_major_version == "7" ))

  - name: shutdown unnecessary services
    service: name={{ item }} enabled=no state=stopped
    with_items: "{{ disable_services | intersect(loaded_services.stdout_lines)}}"
    when: ansible_os_family == "RedHat" and  ansible_distribution_major_version == "6"
    tags:
      - harden
      - test
    ignore_errors: yes
```

And if doesn´t work, try in this other way:

```
  - block:  
    - name: Get registered services
      command: bash -c "chkconfig --list | awk '{print $1}'"
      register:  loaded_services
      changed_when: False
      tags: test

    - name: shutdown unnecessary services
      service: name={{ item }} enabled=no state=stopped
      with_items: "{{ disable_services | intersect(loaded_services.stdout_lines)}}"
      tags:
        - harden
        - test
      ignore_errors: yes

    when: (( ansible_os_family == "RedHat" ) and ( ansible_distribution_major_version == "6" ))

  - block:  
    - name: Get registered services
      command: bash -c "systemctl list-unit-files | grep enabled | cut -d. -f1"
      register: loaded_services
      changed_when: False
      tags: test

    - name: shutdown unnecessary services
      service: name={{ item }} enabled=no state=stopped
      with_items: "{{ disable_services | intersect(loaded_services.stdout_lines)}}"
      tags:
        - harden
        - test
      ignore_errors: yes

    when: (( ansible_os_family == "RedHat" ) and ( ansible_distribution_major_version == "7" ))
```

Comment: Interestingly enough with option one, the variable still gets overwritten by the skipping process: ("loaded_services": "skipped": true)... option two would work without the blocks (using separate variables for each), but that is what i was trying to avoid